# How to replicate background-size:auto with CSS2 without JS

Tags: html, css, image, background, responsive-design

I am learning CSS and made up a problem for myself. I hope to get some help from CSS masters here :)

This is what I am trying to accomplish: A div with some text inside and a background image. Div's width is 100% of it's parent and height depends on text content. The background image should fill the div and have the minimum possible dimensions. Tried to search for answers but haven't found any.

The application of this could be for example a slider, a hero shot or a title with a responsive background and other responsive design applications.

**Question**

How to make responsive background image for div with constrained proportions without CSS3 "background-size" feature and without JS? The div's width is 100% and height depends on it's text content. Background image dimensions should equal either div's height or width as shown on illustration (i.e. image should have smallest possible dimensions).

Is this possible to accomplish at all? Or do I need to use some extra techniques to do this? For example extra @meadia queries with different different images (different dimension) or something else?

**Illustration**

Here is the illustration of how everything should behave:
[Illustration](http://i62.tinypic.com/14mv0b7.jpg)

**Requirements**

The requirements I'm trying to achieve is No "background-size" and No JavaScript. This is for more browser compatibility. The CSS3 background-size:cover does the job almost. Very close. But it isn't compatible with older browsers. The structure is not prescribed. Text and images can be wrapped in any number of divs if needed.

**Attempts**

I've tried to accomplish the task with the following code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/olegovk/gjfpox2a/3/)

The code seems to work ok with smaller images but not with larger images. This presents one of two problems: 1) too low resolution (with small images) OR 2) it isn't clear what the image is about (for larger images).

I haven't used overflow:hidden to make the effect visible.

```
<div class="box">

  <img class="img img11" src="image.jpg" alt="" />

  <h1>Some text here</h1>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

h1 { font: 600 20pt Arial; }

.box {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 70px;
}

.img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; /* Position it in top left corner */
    left: 0px; 
    z-index: -1; /* Put it behind the text */
    border: 2px dashed red;

    /* Preserve aspect ratio */
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

What are your closes't solutions? Hope the question is clear enough and isn't too long. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: "No CSS3" is an extremely arbitrary requirement in this day and age. Media queries are new to CSS3 as well, and are not supported in older browsers either, so you would have to avoid using those too.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Here is clarification: I'd like to avoid "background-size" CSS3 feature.